# using UIImage drawInRect still renders it upside down

Tags: iphone, uiimage, cgcontext

I have read some posts on this website about using drawInRect instead of the CGContext draw methods. It still draws it upside down? I thought using drawInRect would print it right side up with the coordinate system originating at the top left?

```
-(void) drawImage:(UIImage*) image atX:(float) x andY:(float) y withWidth:(float) width andHeight:(float) height onContext:(CGContextRef) context{
UIGraphicsPushContext(context);
[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(x, size.height-y-height, width, height)];
UIGraphicsPopContext();
}
```

Notice I'm doing `size.height-y-height` and if I don't do that it doesn't go where I expect (assuming `drawInRect` using a topleft coordinate system). It renders in the correct spot with the above code but still upside down. HELP!!!!!!

**UPDATE**

Thanks to the answer below this is the working method

```
-(void) drawImage:(UIImage*) image atX:(float) x andY:(float) y withWidth:(float) width andHeight:(float) height onContext:(CGContextRef) context{
UIGraphicsPushContext(context);
CGContextSaveGState(context); 
CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, size.height);
CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);
[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)];
CGContextRestoreGState(context);
UIGraphicsPopContext();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageViewSize);
CGContextRef imageContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

// Draw the image in the upper left corner (0,0) with its actual size
CGContextDrawImage(imageContext, imageViewRect, oldImage.CGImage);

//  As it draws the image from lower right corner, 
//  following code will flip it up side down vertically.


CGContextTranslateCTM(imageContext, 0.0, 0.0);
CGContextScaleCTM(imageContext, 1.0, -1.0);

CGContextDrawImage(imageContext, imageViewRect, oldImage.CGImage);
```

Comment: I'm using stretchableImageWithCapWidth methods on UIImage so I have to use drawInRect to utilize this functionality.

Comment: Try translating Context first and then use drawInRect,if it works for you.