# Drawing lines on top of CGImage

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics

I am currently trying to develop a drawing app. The problem that I've come across is optimising the app's performance.

I have subclassed an `UIView`, in which I am detecting user's inputs.

At first I tried to draw all the lines with CoreGraphics in `draw(_ rect: CGRect)` method but when the number of lines was 10 000+, the lag was very noticeable. So then I thought of creating a CGImage that I would make after every `draw(...)` cycle and then when the next draw cycle came, I would put just the new lines on top of that CGImage, therefore not drawing ALL previous lines again and saving precious time.

I am registering new lines in `touchesBegan()` and `touchesMoved()` methods and then I am calling `self.needsDisplay()`.

This is the code that I am currently using:

```
var mainImage: CGImage?
var newLines: [Line]

override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

    //context?.translateBy(x: 0, y: bounds.height)
    //context?.scaleBy(x: 1, y: -1)

    if let image = mainImage {
        context?.draw(image, in: bounds)
    }

    for line in newLines {
        context?.setStrokeColor(UIColor.black.cgColor)
        context?.setLineWidth(1)

        context?.move(to: line.previousLocation)
        context?.addLine(to: line.location)

        context?.strokePath()
    }
    newLines = []

    mainImage = context?.makeImage()
}
```

Now the problem with it is that the lines I draw are divided in two parts and are mirrored vertically. [(Image split vertically)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7EQSs.png). I have drawn here two continuous lines - one straight line and one curved line. The weird thing is that if I flipped half of the `UIView`, the lines would be aligned continuously with no space between them.

If I uncommented the two lines from my previously mentioned code (`context?.translateBy(x: 0, y: bounds.height)` and `context?.scaleBy(x: 1, y: -1)`), the [image would look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8a3p.png).

The only wrong thing now is that I was drawing on the lower side of the screen and getting results on the upper one.

How do I correct it? What is the proper solution for my problem?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you comment out those two lines, then you are NOT making any changes to the graphics context. If you un-comment them, then you ARE changing the context at each call and not saving it. So I think you're essentially flipping it each time. Not sure if it's that but you should definitely be pushing/saving your context before drawing (and obviously restoring/popping it).

Check out this post:  [using UIImage drawInRect still renders it upside down.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4496191/using-uiimage-drawinrect-still-renders-it-upside-down)

Comment: Yes, indeed! By adding `context?.saveGState()` before and `context?.restoreGState()` after my translation and scale lines, the image is now drawn perfectly! Thanks!